# What is the correct process testing eventlisteners where they depend on the current infowindow

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there any reason why a button click listener within a function which creates markers would not be working, if I have another function which is binding an infowindow where the user can edit the marker information.

I can't add my code right now but what is correct process that should be followed to get this to work/is mine wrong.

Process:

1. Add `rightclick event listener` where the map is initialized to call the create marker function (to create a new marker.
2. Within the create marker function have an `if statement` which specifies which content string (edit or normal display) to bind to the infowindow and binding function.
3. Binding function sets the content of the infowindow to the correct html being the 'input form'.
4. Back in the create marker function I have a save button event listener, (save button is on my edit form) which then saves the new info to the db and updates marker.

I have console.logged the infowindow displaying correctly and also the save button click event. And the click event is not registering anything at all.

**EDIT:** Got onto my drive to get the code, this what the functions mentioned are.

```
function map_initialize()
    {
        var googleMapOptions = 
            { 
                center: mapCenter, // map center
                zoom: 4, //zoom level, 0 = earth view to higher value
                maxZoom: 18,
                minZoom: 2,
                zoomControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL //zoom control size
                },
                scaleControl: true, // enable scale control
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // google map type
            };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_map"), googleMapOptions);         
        start(); //THIS FUNCTION calls the create markers for all in my db.
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(event) 
        {
            create_marker(event.latLng, 'New Event', EditForm, "New", true, true, true, "http://sanwebe.com/assets/google-map-save-markers-db/icons/pin_green.png", -1); //this marker has to stay seperate because type has not been specifyed
        });                                 
    }


    var EditForm = '<p><div class="marker-edit">'+
'<form action="ajax-save.php" method="POST" name="SaveMarker" id="SaveMarker">'+
'<label for="pName"><span>Place Name :</span><input type="text" name="pName" class="save-name" placeholder="Enter Title" maxlength="30" /></label>'+
'<label for="pDesc"><span>Address :</span><textarea name="pDesc" class="save-desc" placeholder="Enter Address" maxlength="90"></textarea></label>'+
'<label for="pDeSS"><span>Description :</span><textarea name="pDeSS" class="save-DeSS" placeholder="Enter Description" maxlength="90"></textarea></label>'+
'<label for="pType"><span>Type :</span> <select name="pType" class="save-type"><option value="Ghost">Ghost</option><option value="UFO">UFO</option>'+
'<option value="Yowie">Yowie</option><option value="Other">Other</option></select></label>'+
'</form>'+
'</div></p><button name="save-marker" class="save-marker">Save Marker Details</button>';


function create_marker(MapPos, MapTitle, MapDesc, MapType, InfoOpenDefault, DragAble, Removable, iconType, mID) 
    {           
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: MapPos,
            map: map,
            draggable:DragAble,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            title: MapTitle,
            icon: iconType
        });

        //Content structure of info Window for the Markers //for the display normally
        var contentString = $('<div class="marker-info-win">'+
            '<div class="marker-inner-win"><span class="info-content">'+
            '<h1 class="marker-heading">'+MapTitle+'</h1>'+
            MapDesc+
            '</span><button name="remove-marker" class="remove-marker" title="Remove Marker">Remove Marker</button>'+
            '<button name="sm-marker" class="sm-marker" title="See More">See More</button>'+
            '<input type="image" name="upvote-marker" class="upvote-marker" src="images/upvote.png" alt="Up Vote Marker">'+
            '<input type="image" name="downvote-marker" class="downvote-marker" src="images/downvote.png" alt="Up Vote Marker">'+
            '</div></div>');    

        if (mID == -1){
            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, EditForm, MapTitle);
            console.log(marker, map, infowindow, EditForm, MapTitle);
            console.log(contentString);
        }else{
                bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, contentString[0], MapTitle);
        }


        //Find remove button in infoWindow
            //Check on button display
        var removeBtn   = contentString.find('button.remove-marker')[0];
        var saveBtn     = contentString.find('button.save-marker')[0];
        var smBtn       = contentString.find('button.sm-marker')[0];
        var upvoteBtn       = contentString.find('input.upvote-marker')[0];
        var downvoteBtn     = contentString.find('input.downvote-marker')[0];   
        //add click listner to remove marker button
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(removeBtn, "click", function(event) {
            remove_marker(marker);
        });

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(upvoteBtn, "click", function(event) {
            upvote_marker(mark,mID);
        });

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(downvoteBtn, "click", function(event) {
            downvote_marker(mark, mID);
        })


        //save button form get
        if(typeof saveBtn !== 'undefined') //continue only when save button is present
        {
            console.log("Button not undefined");
            console.log(EditForm);
            console.log(contentString);
            //add click listner to save marker button
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(saveBtn, "click", function(event) {
                var mReplace = contentString.find('span.info-content'); //html to be replaced after success
                var mName = contentString.find('input.save-name')[0].value; //name input field value
                var mDesc  = contentString.find('textarea.save-desc')[0].value; //description input field value
                var mType = contentString.find('select.save-type')[0].value; //type of marker
                var mDeSS = contentString.find('textarea.save-DeSS')[0].value;//description of marker
                console.log("this is working the click");
                if(mName =='' || mDesc =='')//name and address cant be blank
                {
                    alert("Please enter Name and Description!"); //change wording
                }else{
                    save_marker(marker, mName, mDesc, mType, mDeSS, mReplace); //call save marker function
                    if (mType == "Ghost"){
                    savediconload = 'images/ghost-icon-new.png';
                    } else if (mType == "UFO"){
                    savediconload = 'images/ufo-icon-new.png';
                    } else if (mType == "Yowie"){
                    savediconload = 'images/yowie-icon-new.png';
                    } else if (mType == "Other"){
                    savediconload = 'images/other-icon-new';
                    }
                }
            });
        }

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, html, mapSearchTerm){
        if (html == EditForm){
            infowindow.setContent(html);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            //mark = this;
}else{
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
            infowindow.setContent(html);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            mark = this;
            console.log(mark);
            ImageSearchTerm = mapSearchTerm;
            console.log(ImageSearchTerm);
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: You're unlikely to get decent help here on StackOverflow without posting the relevant code that you have.  Folks here are about 1000% better and faster at helping you fix your exact code than they are at trying to teach in the abstract a problem we don't really understand.

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah I am aware of that but didn't have access to the place where the code was momentarily. Edited in now.

Comment: `bindInfoWindow()` expects HTML as its fourth parameter but, when `mID !== -1`, is passed `contentString[0]`, which is a document fragment, not an HTML string. Suggest you change the token `contentString` to `$content` all through to avoid confusion.

Comment: Also, decide where `create_marker()`'s closing curly brace should be.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Do you mean in all the instances that `contentString` is referred to just change to `$content`. Will this mess up the different contents for the different markers that are already there?

Comment: Yes, change "contentString" to "$content" all through. If you do it correctly, nothing will be messed up, but you will avoid confusing yourself, as when passing a document fragment when it should be an HTML string.

Comment: I've changed that and I'm still getting no response at all. I will have a bit of a play around to see what else could be causing this.

Comment: Sorry, this probably isn't a problem - `infowindow.setContent()` accepts content in string or Node form. However, I still think you should name "contentString" more appropriately.